# Search Sort by Position

Tags: magento-enterprise, blocks, catalogsearch, sorting

I'm trying to sort the products in search result by "Position". Obviously this works in product listing but i found out that it is commented in Block Result.php:

```
/**
 * Set search available list orders
 *
 * @return Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Result
 */
public function setListOrders()
{
    $category = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')
        ->getCurrentCategory();
    /* @var $category Mage_Catalog_Model_Category */
    $availableOrders = $category->getAvailableSortByOptions();
    unset($availableOrders['position']);
    $availableOrders = array_merge(array(
        'relevance' => $this->__('Relevance')
    ), $availableOrders);

    $this->getListBlock()
        ->setAvailableOrders($availableOrders)
        ->setDefaultDirection('desc')
        ->setSortBy('relevance');

    return $this;
}
```

I removed the unset($availableOrders['position']); but Magento throws an SQL error.

Does anyone know how can I achieve this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

category product Collection `is coming over on a category` and Position is an variance of current category .and `catalogsearch is coming on all product here category is not set.that way it is not possible`